# Transfering by calling Action method directly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My controller is:

```
public ActionResult Action1(Action1Model model)
{
   .....
   if (...)
      return Action2(new Action2Model() { .... } );  //**
   else
      return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Action2(Action2Model model)
{ ... }
```

Basically, under certain conditions in Action1 I want to transfer processing to Action2 instead. The above code gives me an error: `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Action2Model', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Action1Model'`.

I can make it work by using this at the ** line:

```
return RedirectToAction("Action2", new { parm1 = ..., parm2 = ... ...});
```

but this approach returns a 302 (extra Http call), exposes all the parameters on the query string, cannot have complex models, and there is no type checking when populating the route values.

Is there a nice way to transfer actions without exposing the model details on the query string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify the view name when calling `View` ASP.NET MVC tries to find the view based on the original action name.

So in your case although you have executed `Action2` and you want to display the `Action2.cshtml` MVC will try to use `Action1.cshtml` with your `Action2Model` which throws this exception.

You can solve this with explicitly writing out the view names in your actions:

```
public ActionResult Action1(Action1Model model)
{
   //....
   if (...)
      return Action2(new Action2Model() { .... } );  //**
   else
      return View("Action1", model);
}

public ActionResult Action2(Action2Model model)
{
     //...
     return View("Action2", model);
}
```